# How to create list of items in a list by index in python

Tags: python, list

I have a list `m`:

```
m = ['ABC', 'XYZ', 'LMN']
```

and I want output as follows:

```
m = [['a','x','l']
     ['b','y','m']
     ['c','z','n']]
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question thereafter

Comment: I suggest you read this SO page on how to ask a good question and then edit this accordingly: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Use `list(zip(*..))` to transpose the nested list, and use list comprehension to create nested list:

```
print(list(zip(*[list(i.lower()) for i in m])))
```

Output:

```
[('a', 'x', 'l'), ('b', 'y', 'm'), ('c', 'z', 'n')]
```

If want sub-values to be lists:

```
print(list(map(list,zip(*[list(i.lower()) for i in m]))))
```

Output:

```
[['a', 'x', 'l'], ['b', 'y', 'm'], ['c', 'z', 'n']]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: @kalpesh Don't forget to accept it if it works :-)

Answer (score 1):

All you need is a list-comprehension, [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to transpose and [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) to convert to lower.

```
   > m=['ABC','XYZ','LMN']
   > [list(map(str.lower, sub)) for sub in zip(*m)]
   [['a', 'x', 'l'], ['b', 'y', 'm'], ['c', 'z', 'n']]
```

Comment: Not OP's desired output

Comment: @U9-Forward. Oops. Did not see the transpose. Thanks!

Comment: Lol, :-), happy you edited it.

Answer (score 0):

```
m=['ABC','XYZ','LMN']
import numpy as np
new_list = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0,0],[0,0,0]]

j = 0

for i in m:
    a = list(i.lower())
    print(a)
    new_list[j] = a
    j = j+1
np.transpose(new_list).tolist()
```

Output:

```
[['a', 'x', 'l'], ['b', 'y', 'm'], ['c', 'z', 'n']]
```